# Detecting which selected item (in a ListView) spawned the ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview

I have two Edit Text in each item of listView.
When user long press on any item in listView I am showing a contextMenu and giving  two options Edit and Delete now how do I know that on which item in listView user long pressed to open the contextmenu.

```
   XML of each item of ListView

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/templateId"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/templateTextId"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
   XML for context menu

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/editTemplate"
          android:title="Edit" />
  <item android:id="@+id/saveTemplate"
        android:title="Save" />
  <item android:id="@+id/deleTemplate"
        android:title="Delete" />
```

```
Code


@Override 
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
          {
                    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");  
                    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");  
                    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");  


                    TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.templateId);
                    selectedId=tv.getText().toString();
                    TextView tvMessage=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.templateTextId);
                    selectedTemplate=tvMessage.getText().toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item In List View Clicked ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }


        @Override  
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
            if(item.getTitle()=="Edit")
            {
                       // Toast.makeText(ShowTemplates.this, "Edit Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ShowTemplates.this);

                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custome_dialog_edit_template);
                        dialog.setTitle("Edit Template");

                        txtMsgTemplate = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextTemplateCustomDialog);
                        txtMsgTemplate.setText(selectedTemplate);
                        Button btnSave=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveEditedTemplate);

                        dialog.show();
              }
```

I tried to find it and I got following

```
       @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

// Get the info on which item was selected
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

// Get the Adapter behind your ListView (this assumes you're using
// a ListActivity; if you're not, you'll have to store the Adapter yourself
// in some way that can be accessed here.)
Adapter adapter = getListAdapter();

// Retrieve the item that was clicked on
Object item = adapter.getItem(info.position);
```

}

But I dont know how to use this Item object.
Is there any other way to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ListViews have a function called `getSelectedItemPosition` that returns an int with the item's position in the adapter. I am pretty sure you could use that. If that is null in `onCreateContextMenu` then try grabbing a reference to it in your `onLongClick listener`.

Comment: getSelectedItemPosition  is returning -1. It is not applicable on longClick event.

Comment: wait, don't you have an itemLongClickListener for your listview? If so the function `public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int position, long arg3)` should give you the position of the longclicked item. Surely that is what you are looking for?